# Malformed params in rails controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am writing an action that will receive a params Hash like this:

`user = {:name=>"Adam", :age=>15, :nickname=>"mynickname"}`

Should I care if params is a correct Hash? What I specifically want to know is if I need to check if user is a hash and not a string, integer or something else.

I wrote this to get the nickname value

```
def nickname
    if params[:user].present?
        params[:user][:nickname].presence
    end
end
```

But it fails if params[:user] is a String and not a hash. Should I write validations for that? If so, What are the best practices for writing them?

Comment: If you're being sent arbitrary data, and it's *normal* to receive arbitrary data, then you need to guard against it. If arbitrary data *isn't* expected, then it's a programming error.

Comment: What do you mean by `params[:user] is a String`? Can you share an example.

Comment: if you are getting these prams through form then you not need to check, this would be hash itself .and why are you creating this nickname method ..please explain your requirement where do you want to use this ..or what you want to do..?

Comment: If the variable user is `{name: "...", age: 15, nickname: "foo"}` then the key `:user` will never be present.

Comment: I will receive this data through a form. I was doing some tests, and I tested the action sending `user = 'hello'`. That would make my action fail. But that kind of request could be sent only by programming a request, not by using the form. So it is not expected to receive that kind of request normally. I was wondering if I should protect against malformed params and write validations so that the action does not crash. @DaveNewton @Mayank @KirtiThorat

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following :

```
nickname = params[:user][:nickname] rescue nil
```

nickname would be nil if any error occurs while browsing the hash.

Be careful with `rescue` that can hide some errors, in this case, it's pretty harmless since all we are doing is fetching values from a hash.